# Not displaying image on the server in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image, jsx

this is the code

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";

const Header = () => {
  return (
    <div className="header">
      <div className="logo-container">
        <img className="logo" src="/assets/logo.jpg" />
      </div>
      <div className="nav-items">
        <ul>
          <li>Home</li>
          <li>About us</li>
          <li>Contact us</li>
          <li>Cart</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

const AppLayout = () => {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Header />
    </div>
  );
};

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(<AppLayout />);
```

[image: It is what i am getting]

please help me as i am new to react.

i am expecting an image to be displayed on the server

Comment: Did you use create-react-app? If so [read this](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/using-the-public-folder/). Or next js? [Read this](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/optimizing/static-assets)

Answer (score 0):

Try to add an alt tag to your code above, if it still doesn't work
Try this:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";

const Header = () => {
  return (
    <div className="header">
      <div className="logo-container">
        <img className="logo" src={process.env.PUBLIC_URL + "/assets/logo.jpg"} alt="Logo" />
      </div>
      <div className="nav-items">
        <ul>
          <li>Home</li>
          <li>About us</li>
          <li>Contact us</li>
          <li>Cart</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

const AppLayout = () => {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Header />
    </div>
  );
};

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(<AppLayout />);
```

Answer (score 0):

import logo on the top separately and give to src of img tag:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
//exact logo path down below//
import logo from "../assets/myLogo.png";

const Header = () => {
  return (
    <div className="header">
      <div className="logo-container">
        <img className="logo" src={logo} />
      </div>
      <div className="nav-items">
        <ul>
          <li>Home</li>
          <li>About us</li>
          <li>Contact us</li>
          <li>Cart</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

const AppLayout = () => {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Header />
    </div>
  );
};

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(<AppLayout />);
```